# Have any deprecated elements or attributes ever been completely abandoned?

Tags: html, css, browser, web-standards

I know the  "align" attribute of the `<div>` tag has been deprecated for some time now, as well as many other attributes. But you can still use it in all browsers. Has any browser ever made a step to actually not support deprecated elements of any kind?

The reason I ask is because I stopped using div align not just because it's frowned upon, but because I thought some day it would be abandoned and unsupported, as oppose to just throwing warnings in my IDE.

Comment: That is exactly what deprecated means. It means do not rely on it being functional in future releases. If you are asking if browsers have done so yet, then I suspect not since so many people are still writing horrible code.

Comment: I haven't seen the `<blink>` tag used much lately :-)

Comment: `<blink>` was [quite literally, a joke](http://www.montulli.org/theoriginofthe%3Cblink%3Etag) though.

Comment: THAT WAS FUNNY.  Thanks for the link, Andrew!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `<basefont>`

Dropped in Firefox.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3875

Comment: The requirements for browsers for the basefont element is defined in HTML5 here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/obsolete.html#other-elements,-attributes-and-apis. IE9 and Chrome already comply. Currently Firefox and Opera don't, but I expect they will do eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Most depreciated elements take several revisions to be worked out *"completely"*.  This is because in the interest of backwards compatibility new browsers retain code for handling these elements.  Most browsers try to avoid this in an effort to retain their own share of the market.  As long as the elements are still used generally then there will most likely be some level of support for them so not to lose those that want to access the content that uses them.

Comment: Can you name an element that has been worked out "completely" then? Wondering which answer is right.

Comment: I am pretty sure that <isindex> support has been removed by the major browsers.  But that is why I put the quotes around completely.  As far as I am aware every tag is supported in at least one of the main stream browsers.  Of course if we go beyond the main stream I am sure that is even more true.

Comment: @BradleyA.Tetreault - Although there is no `<isindex>` *element* in HTML5, the `<isindex>` *tag* is still handled and converted into a form element, an hr element, a label element, a text node, an input element, sometimes another text node, and another hr element. (this only happens if there isn't already an open form element). See http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Cisindex%3E

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no evidence of any deprecated element having been dropped from browsers. Besides, what you ask in the text of your question is about a deprecated attribute, not an element. The answer is the same, though.

Answer (score 0):

I recall battling with the `<layer>` element back in the days of Netscape 4. There were definitely web pages that depended on it, but it's long gone.

But `<layer>` was never standardized, and I am not aware of anything that was in the HTML 2.0, HTML 3.2 or HTML 4.01 standards that has been completely abandoned by HTML5. Sometimes though, implementation requirements are written in such a way that doesn't actually require the browser to do what you'd expect of it or be consistent with what other browsers do. `<blink>` is one such element. `<keygen>` is another.

Note that HTML5 doesn't have "deprecated" elements and attributes, only "obsolete" ones. What this means is that the expectation is that browsers will support them forever, but that web authors should not use them because there are better ways of doing the same thing, or that they are harmful to either authors or users to have them on the page.